# Creating a horizontal menu - inline vs inline-block, vs. floats?

Tags: html, css

While creating my horizontal menu using the `<ul><li>....</li></ul>` I came across a few behaviors that I didn't quite understand.

- ul li {display:inline;} Why does this still cause the menu to be vertical? If I add float:left then it becomes horizontal, but shouldn't it be enough to just set the display to inline?
- On the other hand just doing: ul li {display:inline-block;} results in a horizontal menu without the need of using float. Why is that? Also, when creating horizontal menus which method is better? Or is there a third method that is better than these two?

Comment: it's hard to give you an answer without the relevant css

Comment: Inline elements cannot accept padding and margins, so styling would be limited on display:inline.

Comment: @David My aim here is to just ask more general practices (without needing more css). Basically boiling down to: why is float:left needed to make it show horizontally when using display:inline, yet using display:inline-block doesn't need float:left to show horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline is the default value for display, it just puts thing in the normal order.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think float usually for drop-down menus and inline-block is just for 1 line menu